# A good equation system

Tags: systems-of-equations, radicals, symmetric-functions

Given $a,b,c$ positive numbers, solve the system
 $\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{xz}-x=a$, $\sqrt{yz}+\sqrt{yx}-y=b$ and $\sqrt{zx}+\sqrt{zy}-z=c$,

where $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$.

This only a pretty question. I did it with many changes of variables and now I want to see another solution for it.

My solution begins isolating $\sqrt{x}$ in the first equation, isolating $\sqrt{y}$ and $\sqrt{z}$ in the second and third one, respectively. After, the terms in each of three equations are symmetric, let $S_x=\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x}$ and so on. There are many relations among $S_x,S_y, S_y$. It will be important make $S_a=b+c-a$ and so on and $S=a+b+c$. The solution will be given in term of $S_a, S_b, S_c$ and $S$.

I want to know if someone can give another solution. Thanks!

Comment: Are you entirely sure the last equation doesn't say $\sqrt{zx}+\sqrt{xy}-z=c$, because that makes the system symmetric.

Comment: Sorry, the exercise is correct now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S_a$, $S_b$ and $S_c$ are not zero then
The system solution is

$$x=\frac {S_a (S_b+S_c)^{2}} {4 S_b S_c}$$

$$y=\frac {S_b (S_c+S_a)^{2}} {4 S_c S_a}$$

$$x=\frac {S_c (S_a+S_b)^{2}} {4 S_a S_b}$$

This was obtained after setting

$$a=\frac {S_b+S_c} {2}$$

$$b=\frac {S_c+S_a} {2}$$

$$c=\frac {S_a+S_b} {2}$$

with a new equation system

$$x-y-z+2\sqrt {y z}=S_a$$

$$y-z-x+2\sqrt {z x}=S_b$$

$$z-x-y+2\sqrt {x y}=S_c.$$

Setting $x=X^2$, $y=Y^2$ and $z=Z^2$, using "Derive" software the solution is obtained